# How to access multiple dictionaries values of the same keys from a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
f = ['a','b','c',['me','you','him/her'],
     {'apples':430,'peaches':239,'bananas':839},
     {'apples':123,'peaches':345,'bananas':536}]
```

I know i can access each item in this list if i use slices. For example to access the first dictionary i would do a

```
print(f[4]) #---> {'apples': 430, 'peaches': 239, 'bananas': 839}
```

To access a value of a key in the dictionary i do it like this:

```
print(f[4]['apples']) #---> 430
```

My question is how can i access the values of both apples keys (430,123) in those 2 separate dictionaries, to be displayed one after another automatically?

Can someone please advise, on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do this.

Note that without the `if` statement, you will get a `KeyError` if the `dict` doesn't have the "apples" key and `TypeError` if the item in the  list is not a `dict`

```
>>> f = ['a','b','c',['me','you','him/her'],
...      {'apples':430,'peaches':239,'bananas':839},
...      {'apples':123,'peaches':345,'bananas':536}]
>>> [item['apples'] for item in f if isinstance(item, dict) and 'apples' in item]
[430, 123]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to retrieve the values of multiple dictionaries in the list. This can be done by using a list comprehension to iterate through the list and retrieve the values specified by the key, given that the list element is a dictionary.

Below is a lambda function that works on your list and returns the values stored at 'apples' as a list.

```
finder = lambda l, string: [x[string] for x in l if type(x) == dict]

print(finder(f, 'apples')) # [430, 123]
print(finder(f, 'peaches')) # [239, 345]
```

Comment: Nitpick: if you are going to name a lambda function (i.e., an anonymous function), then don't use a lambda function. If not for sanity's sake, that's the style rule according to PEP8.